# FOSS SDI plain text editor with encoding indicator

Tags: windows, plain-text

looking for open-source SDI (single-document interface, i.e. no document tabs) plain text editor that has text encoding indicator/switcher in some prominent place in its UI, like on toolbar or status bar

also desirable:

1) code folding for any text indented with Tab characters (code folding for relaxed lexer of YAML language can do this, for example notepad++ does it), code folding for text indented with whitespaces may be Ok too

1a) also would like folded segments of text to look like in Eclipse and MS Visual Studio, i.e. one line of text encased into rectangle and indented to same degree as first line of folded segment of text, ability to see contents of folded text segment in tooltip is very welcome as well

2) binary-portable (portable in portableapps.com meaning)

3) no dependencies like .NET, Java etc

4) recognition for both windows and unix end-of-line characters

5) having both windows and linux binaries is welcome

please do not offer notepad++ unless you know how to remove tabs from it (as opposed to just hiding the tab bar)

EDIT:
another desirable property: UI without deliberately sharpened corners (without windows 10 style of GUI)

Comment: CudaText maybe soon will be able to do it- when option "disable UI tabs" will be added. Currently tabs always used.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26415127/how-to-configure-notepad-to-open-files-in-a-single-instance?rq=1 could that help?

Comment: @Sonamor, it still allows to create tabs in any of these three modes, so it is not exactly what I look for

Comment: @RProgram could you please provide a link to where authors say they are going to add it?

Comment: @Mikhail This option (in user.json config) was added in CudaText beta 1.49.2.

Answer (score 1):

**[CudaText](http://uvviewsoft.com/)** editor (free, open source) has all the asked features, and an option to use single tab mode:

`"ui_tab_disabled": true,` (in user.json).

To use **indent-based folding** here, you need to add lexer "Text with indentation" from Addon Manager. It has no filetypes. Activate it using click on statusbar.

[image: example of indent based folding]

Comment: I found CudaText surprisingly confusing... (no offense, maybe I got wrong kind of brain :) )
managed to find license (MPL apparently) only on github - is it mentioned anywhere on website?

Comment: (apparently comments can be edited for only 5 minutes so have to continue in another comment) 

I could easily find how to open/edit preferences of lexers but not how to enable desired lexer, attempts to google for it failed as well, tried to open a file with respective extension (.yaml) - it did not work either...
so how to enable YAML lexer? (and get code folding for indented text as well)

Comment: @Mikhail YAML lexer is in the distro, and it's enabled. It handles file types "yml yaml". These types are configurable in the Lexer Properties dialog. I can help you on CudaText forum/ github.

Comment: RProgram: got it: I tried it without colon symbols which cudatext's yaml lexer seems to require for code folding to happen, unlike notepad++. probably can make it behave like it notepad++ editing cudatext's source code, although it is going to take considerable time. I'll edit the question to clarify my desires. This is already something though, thanks for your effort. unfortunately cannot upvote your answer since I do not have enough rep

Comment: @Mikhail Can you show example of yaml file, which is correct and not folded in Cudatext?

Comment: RProgram: as I wrote in previous comment, I was not clear about why I want yaml code folding, see 1) and 1a) in my (now edited) question. AFAIK colons are required according to yaml syntax so cudatext's lexer is correct, while notepad++'s lexer is less strict which lets me use it to fold any tab-indented text which is my actual goal instead of writing yaml

Comment: @Mikhail See my edited answer about indent based folding.

Comment: RProgram: thanks for your efforts! failed to find anything named "addon manager" or similar in cudaText, managed to install "Text with indentation" lexer by opening its zip file with cudaText. 2 issues remaining: 1) how to make it identify foldable segments without reloading the file? 2) how to make folded segment appear with same indentation as that same segment in unfolded state? also is it possible to make cudaText's UI more like gnome desktop or windows XP? (less angualar)

Comment: @Mikhail 1) nope, UI is always flat, sorry. 2) Thanks for note, lexer Text_with_indentation updated. Now it updates folding if you type text in the middle too. For file size<40K. 3) Addon Manager - in Plugins.

Comment: RProgram: "Plugins" menu is inactive (greyed out) in cudaText for me, so I was unable to open it... what is the reason for 40K limit on file size processed by lexer? is it possible to manually increase it? (for more powerful PCs for example) is it possible to get explicit notification when lexer stops working as expected because this limit is reached? P.S. thanks for fast fix

Comment: @Mikhail About Plugins menu, you miss Python install - http://wiki.freepascal.org/CudaText#Python_integration . About 40K limit, it's in the Text_with_indentation.lcf file (at the end). More than 40K will be ok but w/o fast update.